# getting nth-child of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a table where I need the first two cells of every row clickable (NOT the entire row). When I click the first or the seccond cell, I want to get the value of the third cell of that same row.
To clarify, when I press `a1` I want the alert to show `c1`, If I press `b2` I want it to show `c2` and If  I press `c3` I dont want anything to happen.

As you can see, my `alert($(this).parent(':nth-child(3)').text());` doesn't work.. how can I achieve this?

```js
$('td:nth-child(-n+2)').on("click", function(){
   alert($(this).parent(':nth-child(3)').text()); //Doesn't work
});
```

```css
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td>c3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 'demo' **must** be in question itself

Comment: @A.Wolff eh, what? Elaborate please, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You have to post all relevant code in question itself, otherwise you'll earn downvotes (i guess). EDIT: anyway, this is what you want: `$(this).parent().children(':nth-child(3)').text()`

Comment: Better? I made a super-minimal example, so there's not much code to post. Also, the problem is clearly stated (current behavior, desired behavior)

Comment: Thx for the update, now we can upvote it... :)

Comment: Problem with only jsFiddle is that once link is dead, your question has no more meaning

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use `.closest('tr')` .. to select parent tr  and `.find()` to select `td:nth-child(3)`

```
$('td:nth-child(-n+2)').on("click", function(){
   alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3)').text());
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vnrxb238/1/)

Comment: Hey that user has got suspension for the voting irregularities.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi how is that?? and I don't know why?? he was looking for upvotes as anyone of us looking for even some of us more times looking to be helpful more than upvotes.. I'm not happy with that .. as @A Wolff said before  maybe it wasn't a copy/paste code  maybe his own one and unfortunately to him I posted it faster  :(  .

Comment: He is suspended because of voting irregularities. I think he might got help from some fake users to get more upvotes/ used some duplicate id of himself to get upvotes.  It is not because of not being slower than you. :)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi  what a shock :( .. I though I was fast enough :) :) .. Thanks for let me know :)

Comment: His suspension is for 1 week. After that he will get his points back, except those from the fake ids.

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
$(this).parent().children(':nth-child(3)').text()
```

Select the parent and then a child of it.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnrxb238/3/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
$('td:lt(2)').on("click", function () {
    alert($(this).parent().find("td:eq(2)").text()); //Doesn't work
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnrxb238/2/)

- `lt(2)` will get the specified elements whose index is less than 2
- `eq(2)` will select the element whose index is equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:lt(2)').on("click", function () {
           var text = $(this).parent().find("td:eq(2)").text();
           console.log(text);
     });
 });
```